# Meteorjs Can't get Meteor.user() or Collections sometimes

Tags: meteor

Maybe I just can't find the keyword to find this information,
because I thought this could be basic theory but the thing to be misunderstood easily.

First of all, I'll talk some cases.

1. Server Methods
   Meteor.user()._id returns undefined,
   but Meteor.userId() works in the same position.
2. Template helpers
   Nevertheless WaitOn was declared in iron-router
   some fetching data return null or undefined first,
   but the screen is reloaded after the data comes by computation, so it works.

In these cases, I become not to believe the data concurrency,
so I checked almost every logic to be working without the data.

I think the two case should be working as I expected.
Am I missing something BIG one?? or it's just an irregular case we can see??

Thanks in advance

Comment: (1) I've run into this also. The user id is available **before** the user data is actually published to the client. So you may have a race condition that needs to be fixed with [a guard](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/guards). I'm unclear what you mean by (2) - try showing some code to illustrate your question.

Comment: @David: nice blog post on using `return item && ...` guards. Update to `Template.helpers({...})` perhaps?