# Meteor.user() object

Tags: meteor

MeteorJS. I'm interested in info what is the best practice in keeping user data (logged in user). UserId, CompanyId etc. (data not prone to change)? Session var is not an option because data don't "survive" page refresh.

I constantly need to check Meteor.user().profile.companyId and often there is a problem with famous "Cannot read property 'profile' of undefined".

Comment: I think there's no better place than Meteor.user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping your user data attached to the user's document (either under `profile` or on the root document) is generally the best practice.

I suppose you could define a global helper to [guard](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/guards) the data. Here I'll add a function called `getPP` (get profile property) which I'll add to `Meteor.users`:

```js
_.extend(Meteor.users({
  getPP: function(key) {
    var user = Meteor.user();
    return user && user.profile && user.profile[key];
  }
}));
```

Then you can use it like this:

```js
Meteor.users.getPP('companyId');
```

It will either return the value of the profile property or `undefined` and not throw an error.

Comment: Couldn't you check in the router for this.ready() or check in waitOn for Meteor.user()?

Comment: Like I mention in the guards article, yes you can lean on the router (if using IR) for these things. In practice I prefer to have my templates manage their own subscriptions and error conditions.

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought your answer was responding to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26565282/meteorjs-cant-get-meteor-user-or-collections-sometimes. I will remove it.

Comment: Thank you for answer. My problem is in late initializing of Meteor.user object. So for example, in router, I must put return if user object is not initialized.
        waitOn: function(){ 
            if (!Meteor.user())
                return;
            var user = Meteor.user();

Answer (score 0):

You could use the persistent session package: https://atmospherejs.com/u2622/persistent-session

The downside is you are using global namespace and that is frowned upon. It will be okay if you limit it!